# Валидация контента в amp страницах

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, валидация, amp

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с проблемой валидации `html` контента в `amp` страницах.

Если кто не знает что такое `amp`, то можете прочитать [тут](https://www.ampproject.org/ru/docs/getting-started/).

Суть проблемы такова, есть большой `html` контент для страниц. В нем есть ссылки с таким `href`-ом (`href="javascript:void(0)"`), картинки, и многое другое которое нельзя что бы было в контенте `amp` страниц.

Естественно все это достается из базы данных.

Хотел бы узнать ваше мнение как лучше сделать валидацию этого контента?

**Способ первый:**
Использовать `PHP: DOMDocument`.

**Способ второй:**
Избавиться от лишнего с помощью `regexp`

Пока что другие способы в голову не приходят.

Может еще какие то варианты есть?

Добавлю еще то что сайт на `Symfony 1.4`․

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: `amp страницы`  сильное слово, это  какой-то непонятный фреймворк, со своим валидатором - назовём своими именами) Валидаторы сдохли уже давно и слава богу, но нет, жадные маркетологи и тут пытаются выдать мёртвую лошадь за спящую!  И вообще всё намешано в вопросе - если вам нужно узнать лучший способ работы с HTML ( XML ) - так и спросили бы у гугла, в чём плюсы/минусы regexp либо парсинга в DOM дерево с помощью `DOMDocument`. `simpledom` для этого - очень приятная вещь кстати. Но ИМХО, лучше не покупайте мёртвых лошадей)

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал regexp и DOMDocument вместе. DOMDocument - для преобразования изображений, видео, фреймов и прочего. regexp - для удаление лишнего как раз Ваш случай - (href="javascript:void(0)"), удаление атрибутов, не подходящих тегов и прочего. И так же для Symfony есть библиотека конвертации https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library